# How to sync ArangoDB with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, arangodb, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there any logstash plugin or other kind of mechanism to sync ArangoDB data with elasticsearch?
I'm creating a social network platform and want my users and posts data searchable with ES.
My initial thought was using MongoDB as data store because MongoDb offer ways to sync data to ES via logstash plugin.
However ArangoDB provides graph database capabilities which are quite helpful for storing and querying social relations which is best suited to my requirements. This makes me more inclined towards ArangoDB.

I didn't find any ES/logstash plugin for syncing ArangoDB data with my ES cluster. There are few mentions of a river plugin which exists no more. Two questions:

1. Is there an efficient async way to sync ArangoDB data with ES?
2. If not, should I drop ArangoDB and go with MongoDB which does not provide graph capabilities?

Answer (score -1):

Of Course, There is a way to Sync ArangoDB with ES. I don't remember exactly how to do it, but take a look at this https://www.arangodb.com/2013/11/new-plugin-elasticsearch-arangodb/

Comment: This plugin does not exist any more. ES itself dropped support of river plugins.

Comment: This is not surprising given that rivers are now obsolete..... In this case, why not simply create a wrapper around your data access layer  that also update your ES?

Comment: That is last resort not optimal solution. It increase the load on API and data consistency can also be an issue. One slightly better solution I can think of is using http input connector of logstash + using [arangochair](https://github.com/baslr/arangochair).    Create a separate NodeJs service. Use arangochair to listen collection changes and push changes to logstash input connector.